Missing value in OpenTelemetry Data - How do I interpret it?
I am just getting stated with OpenTelemetry and I am trying to process the raw data for analysis.
When I read from Otel data given by the Otel receive HostMetrics, I get some data that have no "value" key.

It's a metric which I expect to see some sort of "value" but it's absent
Is it expected to have some metric data to have no "value" key to it?

If it is expected, do I interpret that as zero or no data recorded? Similar to how prometheus does it as noted here?
Or is this an error in my Otel Collector?



Here is a protobsample data I got from running an Otel Collector (Contrib) with a HostMetrics Receiver on an AWS EC2 instance.
    metrics {
      name: "system.filesystem.usage"
      description: "Filesystem bytes used."
      unit: "By"
      double_sum {
        data_points {
          start_time_unix_nano: 1713911399000000000
          time_unix_nano: 1716782487551853283
          6: 0x00000004cbeb0000
          7: {
            1: "device"
            2: {
              1: "/dev/nvme0n1p1"
            }
          }
          7: {
            1: "mode"
            2: {
              1: "rw"
            }
          }
          7: {
            1: "mountpoint"
            2: {
              1: "/"
            }
          }
          7: {
            1: "type"
            2: {
              1: "ext4"
            }
          }
          7: {
            1: "state"
            2: {
              1: "used"
            }
          }
        }
        data_points {
          start_time_unix_nano: 1713911399000000000
          time_unix_nano: 1716782487551853283
          6: 0x0000000000000000
          7: {
            1: "device"
            2: {
              1: "/dev/nvme0n1p1"
            }
          }
          7: {
            1: "mode"
            2: {
              1: "rw"
            }
          }
          7: {
            1: "mountpoint"
            2: {
              1: "/"
            }
          }
          7: {
            1: "type"
            2: {
              1: "ext4"
            }
          }
          7: {
            1: "state"
            2: {
              1: "free"
            }
          }
        }
        data_points {
          start_time_unix_nano: 1713911399000000000
          time_unix_nano: 1716782487551853283
          6: 0x0000000001000000
          7: {
            1: "device"
            2: {
              1: "/dev/nvme0n1p1"
            }
          }
          7: {
            1: "mode"
            2: {
              1: "rw"
            }
          }
          7: {
            1: "mountpoint"
            2: {
              1: "/"
            }
          }
          7: {
            1: "type"
            2: {
              1: "ext4"
            }
          }
          7: {
            1: "state"
            2: {
              1: "reserved"
            }
          }
        }
        data_points {
          start_time_unix_nano: 1713911399000000000
          time_unix_nano: 1716782487551853283
          6: 0x000000000060a600
          7: {
            1: "device"
            2: {
              1: "/dev/nvme0n1p15"
            }
          }
          7: {
            1: "mode"
            2: {
              1: "rw"
            }
          }
          7: {
            1: "mountpoint"
            2: {
              1: "/boot/efi"
            }
          }
          7: {
            1: "type"
            2: {
              1: "vfat"
            }
          }
          7: {
            1: "state"
            2: {
              1: "used"
            }
          }
        }
        data_points {
          start_time_unix_nano: 1713911399000000000
          time_unix_nano: 1716782487551853283
          6: 0x0000000006250200
          7: {
            1: "device"
            2: {
              1: "/dev/nvme0n1p15"
            }
          }
          7: {
            1: "mode"
            2: {
              1: "rw"
            }
          }
          7: {
            1: "mountpoint"
            2: {
              1: "/boot/efi"
            }
          }
          7: {
            1: "type"
            2: {
              1: "vfat"
            }
          }
          7: {
            1: "state"
            2: {
              1: "free"
            }
          }
        }
        data_points {
          start_time_unix_nano: 1713911399000000000
          time_unix_nano: 1716782487551853283
          6: 0x0000000000000000
          7: {
            1: "device"
            2: {
              1: "/dev/nvme0n1p15"
            }
          }
          7: {
            1: "mode"
            2: {
              1: "rw"
            }
          }
          7: {
            1: "mountpoint"
            2: {
              1: "/boot/efi"
            }
          }
          7: {
            1: "type"
            2: {
              1: "vfat"
            }
          }
          7: {
            1: "state"
            2: {
              1: "reserved"
            }
          }
        }
        aggregation_temporality: AGGREGATION_TEMPORALITY_CUMULATIVE
      }
    }
  }

